# How to reproduce this kind of wavy line?

Tags: tcolorbox, mdframed, decorations

I was wondering how to reproduce this kind of vertical wave line to the left of the text :
[image]

Answer (score 13):

One possible approach using the `bclogo` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{bclogo}[logo=\relax,barre=wave,noborder=true]{} 
\lipsum[2]
\end{bclogo}

\end{document}
```

[image]